# How to select only one row if a value of a column occurse multiple times in the result?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have a table like this on:

| AttributeA | AttributeB | AttributeC | AttributeD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | **EQUALITY** | D |
| 123 | B | **EQUALITY** | D |
| 456 | B | C | D |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

My goal is, to create a Select-Query where the result only contains one row with an equal AttributeC - no matter of the count of rows with the same value in this column.

The other Attributes do not matter. So I want this:

| AttributeA | AttributeB | AttributeC | AttributeD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A *or* 123 | B | **EQUALITY** | D |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have already tried some WHERE-Clauses, but I found no way to specify that I want to have the row atleast once in my result.

Something like this was my plan with an unique ID.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.ID = (SELECT TOP(1) FROM Table1 as tempTable where Table1.ID = tempTable.ID)
```

I think I know, why this doesn't work, but I could not found a way to make it work. (and I'm not sure, that it is possible with a WHERE-Clause).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by attributeC order by attributeC) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

A somewhat more concise, but less performant method is:

```
select top (1) with ties t1.*
from table1 t1
order by row_number() over (partition by attributeC order by attributeC) ;
```